# Defining source data on Pivot table template for VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I found this code on Spreadsheetguru and I have an issue with editing the code.

```
Sub CreatePivotTable()
'PURPOSE: Creates a brand new Pivot table on a new worksheet from data in the ActiveSheet
'Source: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim StartPvt As String
Dim SrcData As String

'Determine the data range you want to pivot
  SrcData = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Range("A1:R100").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Create a new worksheet
  Set sht = Sheets.Add

'Where do you want Pivot Table to start?
  StartPvt = sht.Name & "!" & sht.Range("A3").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Create Pivot Cache from Source Data
  Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=SrcData)

'Create Pivot table from Pivot Cache
  Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
    TableDestination:=StartPvt, _
    TableName:="PivotTable1")

End Sub
```

Why is it not possible for me to Define **SrcData** as Worksheets("SHEETNAME").Range("A1:A100")? It returns a type 13 error: mismatch. I tried finding answers online and most examples referred the SrcData for ActiveSheet.Range instead of a defined sheet.

Thank you!

It would also greatly help if you could show me how an example pivot would work for the Sheet("PivotExp") on this sheet.https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkdug.jpg

Thank you so much!

Comment: `SrcData` is declared as a String, not a Range. It is better to use range addresses as the source for pivot tables, not range objects, so I suggest you leave the code as it is.

Comment: You need to provide the address as a string: `SrcData  = "SHEETNAME!A1:A100"`

Answer (score -1):

> Why is it not possible for me to Define SrcData as
>   Worksheets("SHEETNAME").Range("A1:A100")?

Pivot table works on 2 dimensional data (tabular form), i.e rows and columns, but with A1:A100 your are supplying only 1 dimensional data (list form). Also you need to assign source data as per syntax rules.

> ```
> It returns a type 13 error: mismatch.
> ```

Mismatch error due to above reason.

> It would also greatly help if you could show me how an example pivot
>   would work for the Sheet("PivotExp") on this
>   sheet.https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkdug.jpg

Due to some reason, image was not visible, but instead you can visit following example link : http://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/pivot-tables-examples/ which show how to create Pivot Tables with VBA code.
Since, your given code is missing lot of Pivot related information, a Pivot wont' get formed but by visiting above link you can have idea, what things are missing in it.

Comment: This is both wrong and not particularly helpful. You can indeed create a pivot table from one column, and you didn't address the actual question about why the Type Mismatch error occurs.

Comment: @Rory Yes My question was for the mismatch, even if I try:

Dim pivotexp As Worksheet
Set pivotexp = Worksheets("PivotExp")

'Determine the data range you want to pivot
  SrcData = pivotexp.Range("A6:E26")

still returns the same error

Comment: @eddy I addressed that in my comment on your original question.

Comment: @rory Sorry, just to clarify if i understood ur answer

Define SrcData as Worksheets("SHEETNAME").Range("A1:A100") would lead to a RANGE OBJECT, when it is better to define source as RANGE ADDRESS (i.e. ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Range("A1:R100").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)). correct?

Comment: @eddy Yes, although you should really use: `"'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & Range("A1:R100").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1))`